# asyncTask not working for me

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an IME service class and a long operation method in it. I want to run the LongOperation task in a asyncTask class that is in the IME Service class.

```
     public class Myimeservice extends InputMethodService
        implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListene {
    //...
    //some code here....
    //...

    public void setDictionary(){
          //....
    }

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Myimeservice parent;

        public LongOperation(Myimeservice pim){
            parent = pim;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                Myimeservice tmp = new Myimeservice();
                tmp.setDictionary();
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //app.hideLoading();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //app.showLoading();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

When i run it, the application forced to close. please help me.

Comment: Please, add the LogCat output so we can better understand what is the error.

Comment: You do not need to override every method. Only these you use.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is somewhere in your `public void setDictionary()` method. 
I assume that you are manipulating a variable that is bound to the UIThread/MainThread, the application will crash since doInBackground is on another Thread.

Instead make the `setDictionary()` method return the dictionary and return it instead of "Executed" in `doInBackground()`.

This will call the `onPostExecute(Object result)` which is run on UIThread/MainThread.

Something like this:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Dictionary> {

@Override
protected Dictionary doInBackground(String... params) {
     Myimeservice tmp = new Myimeservice();
     Dictionary dict = tmp.setDictionary();
     return dict;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Dictionary result) {
                //do what ever you meant to do with it;
}

}
```

If you are not expecting any result from it you can just do:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 tmp.setDictionary();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The setDictionary() method manipulates some variables of service only and call one method of Myimeservice and setDictionary() return nothing(void). I want to do this heavy work of class in other thread.

Comment: I want to call setDictionary() method of Myimeservice from asynctask class. please help me.....

Comment: Runnable may be a better choice than. But since it crashes you must be manipulating UIThread variables.
Instead of Myimeservice tmp = new Myimeservice(); shouldn't you be calling parent.setDictionary()??

Answer (score 0):

I use the Runnable instead of AsyncTask and the problem solved.

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            setDictionary();
        }
    };
```

this code is in onCreate() method of service.
Tanks a lot Tristan Richard.